# Finding Maximum in an array; using four threads in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I've been trying to write a program to find the max value in an array. 
I know how to use threads to find it but to get the right answer I need to use .join ().

I don't get why it wouldn't find the max without using .join (); and if I use .join () then the running time of the program would be as much as the same program without threads; so if it's the only way to run my thread and it doesn't fasten the process why do we use threads?

```
public void run() {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (array[i] > threadMax) {
            threadMax = array[i];
        }
    }        
}
```

This is my run method; I give each thread quarter of the array and then find the max between them.
this works but if only I use .join() but I don't want to slow down the program.
what else can I do?
Edit: This is my code:

```
    ThreadMax[] findMax = new ThreadMax[4];
    findMax[0] = new ThreadMax(array, 0,array.length/4);
    findMax[1] = new ThreadMax(array, array.length/4, (2*array.length)/4);
    findMax[2] = new ThreadMax(array, (2*array.length)/4, (3 * array.length) / 4);
    findMax[3] = new ThreadMax(array, (3 * array.length) / 4, array.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        findMax[i].myThread.start();
        try {
            findMax[i].myThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    int[] topFour = new int[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        topFour[i] = findMax[i].threadMax;
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if(result < topFour[i])
            result = topFour[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Max = " + result);
```

and my ThreadMax class:

```
int start;
int end;
int threadMax;
int[] array;
Thread myThread;

ThreadMax(int[] array, int start, int end) {

    this.array = array;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;

    myThread = new Thread(this);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (array[i] > threadMax) {
            threadMax = array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the current thread does an equal amount of work as 3 background threads then using join() will take about the same time, but ensures that all threads have done their work before continuing.

Comment: BTW You want the threads to work at the same time, so they **shouldn't** be locking on anything or this won't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use `synchronized`? You want to run all threads parallel, this avoids it.
You need to join the threads to see when they have finished. The code you call your threads from is another thread that doesn't know when these four threads are done with their work. join() waits for this moment.

> this works but if only I use .join()

"works" means you don't have the correct result without join()? Yes because the calling code (that you unfortunately didn't show) probably runs over the thread-starting lines and comes to it's end even before the threads were started.

#### Edit

Now as more code is available it's clear to me. You execute a loop:
start the first thread
wait for the first thread
start the second thread...

No thread is started until the previous one has finished!

You need separate loops. FIRST start all threads in one loop, THEN wait for them to finish in a second loop.

Comment: thanks! but I'm trying to avoid .join(). what is the difference if I don't use thread at all if I'm going to wait for them to run sequentially ?

Comment: Why avoid join? If you use threads you need to wait until they are ready. That's what join does. You slow down your threads with synchronize, that's why your program is not faster. But this is not a matter of join. There is no difference if you use one single thread (there is no "no threads", there always is one thread) or x threads but don't allow them to run parallel. That's what you do currently :-)

Comment: I erased "synchronize" but it still is slower than the same program without threads. I can't understand how multithreading helps if I have to wait and .join() doesn't let them run parallel?

Comment: The calling thread waits while four other threads do the work in 1/4 (theoretically) of the time than one thread would do. join() doesn't prevent the threads from executing parallel - where did you put them?  Write output to control what happens, when which thread is entered and left and during it's work. Do you have more than one cpu core? Otherwise threads won't help you. Show your entire code, the calling code too.

Comment: I'm put the join() right after I start each thread. I have more than one CPU core. and I added my code too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Thread.join()` method on the `main thread.` It ensures that wait for the thread until finish it's job. Otherwise main thread can be terminated before your threads are done.

Answer (score 0):

The class could implement `comparable<arraylist>` and you could use the `Collections.max(arrayList)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the input but this doesnt answer the question, does it?